# How can I customize my nft collection with the smart contract?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I want to add a logo and banner image on my nft collection. What I want to do is to add the logo and banner image when i deploy my contract so that no matter what the marketplace platform is I always get the image  and banner image for my collection.Otherwise I have to add logo and banner image seperately on each marketplace platform i.e opensea, Larva Labs/CryptoPunks etc.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opensea provides a standard in the form of `contractURI()` which can be added to the contract, and provides default values to the NFT collection. Check out [this](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata) article to know more. I think this can resolve your query.